# Running two .jar files at execution

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to follow the README for a new module I am trying to use, and it is specificed to run this input:

> java -cp jar_one.jar:jar_two.jar mo.du.le.file

Except when I try this I get an error that the class of mo.du.le.file cannot be found or loaded. I try running it also with just one jar file, it does find/load mo.du.le.file, except that it crashes when it reaches a point where the other jar is needed.

I've been trying some solutions for multiple classpaths here on SO, but I either get the same error message, or a similar error message saying the second jars class could not be found or loaded.

Can anybody help me out with this?

Just as a note, I never have problems running other jar or java files, and am using cygwin bash as my terminal.

Comment: Where are those jar files? Is that in the same directory from where you are running java command?

Comment: Yes they are in the same directory as where I am running the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `:` (colon) with `;` (semicolon).

Since you mentioned Cygwin, it would appear that you are on Windows, and a "path" is separated by `;`. The `:` separator is used on Linux (and similar OS's like Mac OS X).

Comment: So I tried this, and it's telling me that it cannot find the jar file. It's confusing because if I try to run with either of the jars by themselves, it finds them fine but crashes because the absence of the second one.

Comment: @user2967087 If you are running from Bash, `;` is a command separator, so you need to quote the value: `java -cp "jar_one.jar;jar_two.jar" mo.du.le.file`

Comment: wow yes that was the solution, it is working now by combination of this answer and your comment.